# Write Hashicorp Vault secret as multiline to YAML

Tags: json, yaml, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, helm3

Given this Vault secret:

```
{
  "config": "test.domain.com:53 {errors cache 30 forward . 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2}"
}
```

How do I retrieve it and write it to a YAML file so that is in the following format:

```
test.domain.com:53 {
    errors
    cache 30
    forward . 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2
}
```

Using the following command saves it on a single line, which won't work with our project.

```
vault kv get -format=json ${VAULT_PATH}/coredns-custom | jq -r .data.data >> coredns-custom.yaml
```

I've tried inserting linebreaks \n in the secret, but the retrieval command doesn't parse them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\n` does work, it's a YAML feature, not a feature of the retrieval. Please show exactly what you did. General please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You query some value `.data.data` which does not correspond to what you show as JSON data. `jq -r .config < test.json` does write out `\n` properly. And finally, your output is not YAML, either it's something else or this is not what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` should work in the value that stored in Vault.

How about storing the value as following into vault directly? eg

```
test.domain.com:53 {\n
    errors\n
    cache 30\n
    forward . 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2\n
}\n
```